# Moved my Wordpress site to a Linode server, featured images no longer resizing?

Tags: wordpress, image-processing, ubuntu-10.04, linode

As the title heading reads. I've moved my Wordpress site over to a Linode finally, but I've noticed that my featured images are no longer automatically resizing?

I've installed Virtualmin on this Linode and some security stuff, but do I need to install CURL or anything? Running Ubuntu 10.04.

Please let me know any other information you require and I'll do my best to comply, thanks!

Comment: do you have GD lib installed and enabled on the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Obmerk's comment, installing php5-gd on my linode solved everything!

Comment: I am glad it helps ... a little upvote even to the comment can help :-)